# How can I remove wood filler from knots in cherry furniture?

Tags: repair, wood, table

My sister bought some new Amish cherry furniture from Ohio
When it arrived they had filled knots with some kind of wood filler. Is it possible to get it out of knots?

[image][image]

Comment: Frankly, I'd send it back.  Contact the manufacturer with these photos and say it's unacceptable.

Comment: Agree that this isn't top quality furniture, but a remedy depends on how the article was described in the first place. (If they said "clear" or "no knots", then you obviously have a good argument.)

Comment: you can dig it out, but it would likely look worse with a smooth bore side than the natural "jaggies"

Comment: Wow those look bad, I've not seen that with the pieces I have purchased. I would contact the seller and at least request the type of filler used so you know what to use to soften it.

Comment: if you like the table other than the filler, have them install dutchman patches. skillyfully installed dutchman can be attractive even if noticeable.
if vendor won't do it, have a local woodworking expert do it.

Comment: A router with a small round bit or a rotary tool would do, as would any number of hand tools. I'd try staining it very dark first, like a natural knot might be. Almost black.